# Inserting "raw" XML string into a XElement

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

I'm trying to load a node (in string format) into a XElement.
Although this should be easy enough i'm finding some problems:

- The node I'm trying to load contains namespace references in some sub-nodes
- When I try to use `XElement.Load()` or `Xelement.Parse()` I get the expected not defined namespace error

I know the solution is to create a surrounding node with the namespace definitions and then load the whole thing, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution that doesn't involve string operations.

Here's my failed attempt :(

I have a collection of namespace attributes:

```
private readonly List<XAttribute> _namespaces;
```

This is already populated and contains all the necesary namespaces.
So, to embed my XML string into another node I was doing this:

```
var temp = new XElement("root", (from ns in _namespaces select ns), MyXMLString);
```

But as I expected as well, the content of MyXMLString gets escaped and becomes a text node.
The result I get is something like:

```
<root xmlns:mynamespace="http://mynamespace.com">&lt;mynamespace:node&gt;node text&lt;/node&gt;</root>
```

And the result I'm looking for is:

```
<root xmlns:mynamespace="http://mynamespace.com">
<mynamespace:node>node text</node>
</root>
```

Is there a neat way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably your XML text is actually well formed (note the namespace qualifier on the closing tag):

```
var xml = "<mynamespace:node>node text</mynamespace:node>";
```

In which case you can use this to manually specify the namespaces:

```
var mngr = new XmlNamespaceManager( new NameTable() );
mngr.AddNamespace( "mynamespace", "urn:ignore" ); // or proper URL
var parserContext = new XmlParserContext(null, mngr, null, XmlSpace.None, null);
```

Now read and load:

```
var txtReader = new XmlTextReader( xml, XmlNodeType.Element, parserContext );
var ele = XElement.Load( txtReader );
```

Works as expected. And you don't need a wrapper 'root' node. Now this can be inserted into any as an `XElement` anywhere.

Comment: Yes, the XML fragment is well formed, I made a mistake while typing the example. Will this method allow me to access the "<mynamespace:node>" once loaded in the XElement?

Comment: Absolutely, try it and see. You'll get a well formed XElement that represents the XML string.